# Iterate an array of hashes in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, iteration

I was iterating through all the entries of a dictionary source file, for each entry I use one `hash` to store some relations between the `headword`(only one `headword` per entry; as the `value` of a `hash`) and its corresponding `topic`(maybe there're more than one `topic`s in one entry; as the `key` of a `hash`), and after iterating through each entry I add the `hash` into an `array` and put all `hash`es together in that array by the end of all iteration, then I'm gonna do something with that `array` of `hash`es.

> Note:Different `hash`es may contain the same `key`, so I can't convert the all `hash`es to an `array` and then convert them back to one single `hash`, that will erase the duplicate `key`s.

I get the following error upon run the code:

> Can't use string ("art") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at this line: `while (my ($key, $value) = each %{$hash_ref}){`

"art" is one of the topics mentioned above.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature ':all';
my $filename='a';
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
open(DICT, "<", $filename)
    or die "Cannot open '$filename': $!";

my @array;    

while(<DICT>){
    my %h;
    my $hw=$1  if /(^.*?)(?=<link rel)/;
    while (m/\<SUBJECT\-AREA\>(.*?)\<\/SUBJECT\-AREA\>/g) {
        $h{$1}=$hw;
    }

    push(@array, %h);

    END {
        for my $hash_ref (@array){
            while (my ($key, $value) = each %{$hash_ref}){
                print "$key\n\@\@\@LINK=$value\n</>\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't *have* an array full of hashes (hash references) to iterate over. When you do

```
 push(@array, %h);
```

it is flattening `%h` into a list of key/value pairs and pushing that list onto the end of `@array`.

What you meant to do instead was

```
push @array, \%h;
```

which pushes a reference to `%h` onto `@array`.

Comment: @jonah_w it's always a good idea to use Data::Dumper (or Data::Printer) to make sure that the data you're working with is what you expect it to be.